# Logic error in playing card combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

**Premise:** I'm trying to develop a card game to play with my friends. From a standard Western deck of 52 cards (or a double deck of 104 for more players), each player will maintain a hand of 8 cards. Players will attempt to match certain patterns (4 of a kind, 4 in a row, etc.), but always consisting of 4 cards. In order to assign point values, I want to know how common each pattern is. I've done calculations for over a dozen patterns, but I discovered by accident that I'd been using faulty logic.

**Basic Example:** For easy inspection, I've reduced my technique to a simple example. Suppose I draw two cards from the deck. How many possible pairs will have at least one red card? By my technique, I would start by saying there are 26 possible red cards to choose for the first  card -- thus, $\binom{26}{1}$. Once that's done, there are 51 cards left, and any one will be acceptable, so the total is $\binom{26}{1}\binom{51}{1} = 1326$. Of course, this is wrong because the total number of unique pairs in the deck is $\binom{52}{2} = 1326$.

**Request:** For the first part, why is my logic wrong? (I have done a little research on StackExchange, and started to understand this.) For the second part of my request, is there a reasonable way to adapt the technique to get correct answers? If  I would have to consider large numbers of cases individually, I might just use a computer to brute-force the solution. That would be its own fun, but lacks elegance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look up Wikipedia for the way number of poker hands are computed, and apply the principles you learn to your problem. For the particular problem you started with, try using the complement, n(any 2) - n(both black) to understand the flaw in your computation.

Comment: Double counting. Any pair consisting of two red cards is counted twice: once with one red card counted first, once with the other counted first. The correct counting is e.g. take all pairs, and subtract those that are both black, i.e. ${52\choose 2}-{26\choose 2}$.